# How to generate cross table for multiple variables in the column using dplyr and gtsummary

Tags: r, dplyr, pivot-table, gtsummary

This is the data

```
# Generate data
set.seed(123)
member <- sample(c("Yes", "No"), 100, replace = TRUE)
author <- sample(c("Yes", "No"), 100, replace = TRUE)
review <- sample(0:10, 100, replace = TRUE)
publish <- sample(0:10, 100, replace = TRUE)
pay <- sample(0:10, 100, replace = TRUE)
data <- data.frame(member, author, review, publish, pay)
```

I have tried to use tbl_cross but I keep getting an error using this code

```
data %>%
  mutate(across(c(review, publish, pay), ~cut(., breaks = c(-Inf, 4.5, 5.5, Inf),
                                              labels = c("No", "Maybe", "Yes"),
                                              include.lowest = TRUE), .names = "{.col}_group")) %>% 
  select(member, author, ends_with("group")) %>%
  tbl_cross(
    row = member,
    col = select(ends_with("group")),
    margin = "row",
    missing = "no", 
    statistic = list(all_categorical() ~ "{n} ({p}%)"),
    digits = list(all_categorical() ~ c(0, 1))
  ) %>%
  add_p(test = all_categorical() ~ "fisher.test")
```

Error:
! Error in `col=` argument input. Select from ‘member’, ‘author’, ‘review_response’, ‘publish_response’,
‘pay_response’
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

The desired result should have row and column totals for the multiple variables.

[image]

Comment: Could you please show your desired result.

Comment: @Elin I have updated my question with the desired output. Thanks

Comment: Great so they are next to each other rather than crossed three ways.

Answer (score 2):

So how to make cross tabs is one of the more frustrating things in R.
gtsummary is one of the better solutions.  However, cross_tbl() is limited to one column variable (you are trying to use three).  If you want to use that approach you would need to create three objects and merge them.
This is obviously missing grace notes.

```
set.seed(123)
member <- sample(c("Yes", "No"), 100, replace = TRUE)
author <- sample(c("Yes", "No"), 100, replace = TRUE)
review <- sample(0:10, 100, replace = TRUE)
publish <- sample(0:10, 100, replace = TRUE)
pay <- sample(0:10, 100, replace = TRUE)
df <- data.frame(member, author, review, 
                 publish, pay) |>
      dplyr::mutate(across(c(review, publish, pay),
                           ~cut(.,
                                breaks = c(-Inf, 4.5, 5.5, Inf),
                                labels = c("No", "Maybe", "Yes"),
                                include.lowest = TRUE), 
                                .names = "{.col}_group")) 
t1 <- df |>     tbl_cross(
          row = member,
          col = review_group,
           percent = c( "column"),
          margin = c("column", "row"),
          missing = c( "ifany"),
          missing_text = "Unknown",
          margin_text = "Total"
     ) |> add_p()
t2 <- df |>     tbl_cross(
     
     row = member,
     col = publish_group,
     percent = c( "column"),
     margin = c("column", "row"),
     missing = c( "ifany"),
     missing_text = "Unknown",
     margin_text = "Total"
) |> add_p()

t3 <- df |>     tbl_cross(
     
     row = member,
     col = pay_group,
     percent = c( "column"),
     margin = c("column", "row"),
     missing = c( "ifany"),
     missing_text = "Unknown",
     margin_text = "Total"
) |> add_p()

tbl_merge(list(t1, t2, t3))
```

Comment: I was hoping I won't have to do that for each variable as I have 40 of them, but this is helpful and thank you @Erin.

Comment: You can create a function and then lapply through that with the variable names.  But make sure you just get the names, not the columns of data.  Or just loop.

Comment: @Erin I'm fairly new to R, I don't know how to do that yet. I'm half way through using this code.